# DBmemo not saving data

Tags: delphi, firedac

Please help me understand the reason why DBMemo does not save changes made via insert from ListBox. The ListBox is used as a list of wildcard phrases. When double clicked, it should appear in the DBMemo. It appears, but once the cursor is inserted into the DBMemo, the text disappears.

`cxDBMemo1.Lines.Add(ListBox2.Items[ListBox2.ItemIndex]);`

Used FireDAC, ADOQuery. Various update modes. But it didn't help.

If you insert the text in the field itself manually, then everything is in order. But it is worth inserting programmatically, but the text is not saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Delphi applications ,we have toggle for editing of `DataSet` . call `Edit()` for enable it.

```
DataSet1.Edit()
```